# Boto3 script to create instance tag

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-3.4, boto3

I am trying to create a new tag called `Name` and value hostname `apphostname` for an Amazon EC2 instance.

Below is my code, and it is failing with this error message:

```
>>> ec2.create_tags(["i-1923943832310"], {"name": "apphostname"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 157, in _api_call
    "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
TypeError: create_tags() only accepts keyword arguments.
>>>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [Create Tags](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags). It expects key value arguments. `Tags` is a list of dictionaries. You can create more than one tag if you want.

```
ec2.create_tags(Resources=['i-1923943832310'], Tags=[{'Key':'name', 'Value':'apphostname'}])
```